# Python Function does not return value

Tags: python

I'm working in Python and I wrote this simple function.  I'm getting anything returned.

```
def add(a, b):
    total = a + b
    return total

add(6, 3)
```

I've tried installing and uninstalling the latest version.

Comment: Use print(add(6,3)).

Answer (score 1):

In REPL like Python interpreter or IPython, the output is evaluated and displayed in the next line when the function which returns a value is run

```
In [9]: def add(a, b): 
   ...:     total = a + b 
   ...:     return total 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                             

In [10]: add(6,3)                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[10]: 9
```

But same doesn't happen when you run it via an IDE say PyCharm in which case you need to explicitly print the output by [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

```
def add(a, b):
    total = a + b
    return total

print(add(6,3))
```

Output then will be `9`

Answer (score 1):

It's returned and then discarded because the returned value is not used anywhere. If you want to see it printed, then print it:

```
print(add(6,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to print the result:

```
def add(a, b):
    total = a + b
    return total

print(add(6, 3))
```